# Why is python giving me an UnboundLocalError when I run this program?

Tags: python, function, compiler-errors, global-variables

### Background

I am currently experimenting with computer learning, and I made a function where you enter "true" or "false" and the computer learns which boolean it is, after which the program prints the percent of correct guesses the computer made:

```
import math
import random
endgame = False
def oneround():
    Q1max = 1
    Q1min = -2
    guess = False
    answer = 0
    while guess == False:
        useranswer = input("True or False?")
        if useranswer == "True" or useranswer == "true":
            answer = True
            guess = True
        elif useranswer == "False" or useranswer == "false":
            answer = False
            guess = True
        
    corrects = 0
    incorrects = 0 
    howmanytimes = int(input("how many times do you want the computer to guess? (If you want to end the game, type in letters instead of a number.) "))
    for x in range(0,howmanytimes):
        choice = random.randint(Q1min,Q1max)
        if choice >= 0:
            guess = True
        else:
            guess = False
        if guess == answer:
            corrects += 1
            if guess == True:
                Q1max += 1
            else:
                Q1min -= 1
        else:
            incorrects += 1
            if guess == False:
                Q1max += 1
            else:
                Q1min -= 1
    percent = (corrects/howmanytimes)*100
    print ("The computer learned to guess correctly",(str(math.floor(percent))+"%"),"of the time.")
while endgame == False:
    try:
        oneround()
    except ValueError:
        endgame = True
```

I then tried to improve my program by adding 2 global variables, `percentavg` and `percentavgnum`, that will average all the success percentages together at the end of the program:

```
import math
import random
endgame = False
global percentavg
global percentavgnum
percentavg = 0
percentavgnum = 0
def oneround():
    Q1max = 1
    Q1min = -2
    guess = False
    answer = 0
    while guess == False:
        useranswer = input("True or False?")
        if useranswer == "True" or useranswer == "true":
            answer = True
            guess = True
        elif useranswer == "False" or useranswer == "false":
            answer = False
            guess = True
        
    corrects = 0
    incorrects = 0 
    howmanytimes = int(input("how many times do you want the computer to guess? (If you want to end the game, type in letters instead of a number.) "))
    for x in range(0,howmanytimes):
        choice = random.randint(Q1min,Q1max)
        if choice >= 0:
            guess = True
        else:
            guess = False
        if guess == answer:
            corrects += 1
            if guess == True:
                Q1max += 1
            else:
                Q1min -= 1
        else:
            incorrects += 1
            if guess == False:
                Q1max += 1
            else:
                Q1min -= 1
    percent = (corrects/howmanytimes)*100
    percentavg += percent
    percentavgnum += 1
    print ("The computer learned to guess correctly",(str(math.floor(percent))+"%"),"of the time.")
while endgame == False:
    try:
        oneround()
    except ValueError:
        endgame = True
print ("The computer guessed correctly",(str(math.floor(percentavg/percentavgnum))+"%"),"of the time")
```

### Problem

But I keep getting this error whenever I run the program:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 49, in <module>
    oneround()
  File "main.py", line 44, in oneround
    percentavg += percent
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'percentavg' referenced before assignment
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Instead of using a *global* variable, have your function return the calculated value(s); assign the return value(s) to the module level variables, pass the module level variables to the function.

Comment: @wwii Can you phrase that a bit more simply?

Comment: See my answer ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `global`. Put it at the top of the function with the variable names after it. Like this: `global percentavg, percentavgnum`
**NOTE**: The names must be comma-separated.

Comment: This returns a syntax error for that line.

Comment: This is _somewhat_ correct, but doesn't explain _why_! `global` makes sure the referenced name is from the global scope (otherwise it can't be differentiated from a new name in the scope of the function). Put one per line

Comment: @ti7 Oh yeah, forgot about that. They can be all on one line if you separate them by commas.

Comment: So why was I getting an error? Please include that in your answer.

Comment: @jeffthechicken Done.

Comment: @Blue But WHY was I getting the error? I want to learn from this so I don't make the same mistake later.

Comment: @jeffthechicken Ah, I misunderstood you. Python doesn't like it when you don't put commas between the variable names. Not sure how I forgot to include that.

Comment: @Blue I understand that, but why does your solution fix the code, and what was wrong with my code before I added your global statement?

Comment: All of this is explained in the link i posted in my answer (https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value). When tou add `global my_variable` IN the function as @Blue said, it gives you access to the outer scope variable (declared outside the function), that's why it fixes the code.

Comment: @Rivers this is a simpler way to make it work, so I upvoted yours for helping with **why** I got an error, but selected this one for giving me the best answer.

Comment: @jeffthechicken I upvoted it. That was a good question, but generally we don't ask for upvotes. Best way to put it is that this is a forum, not a social media network.

Comment: @Blue my bad, sorry

Answer (score 2):

This problem is related to how Python determines the scope of a variable.

You can notice that the error occurs when you try to increment `percentavg` via `percentavg += percent`.

So you are trying to *assign* a new value to `percentavg`.

The thing is that in Python, when you assign a value to a variable, the variable becomes a *local* variable. But `percentavg` has not been defined in this scope (the scope of `oneround()`, and so you get this `UnboundLocalError`.

All of this is explained in details here:
https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value

You have at least 3 options:

1. Define the variables in `oneround()`:

```
def oneround():
    percentavg = 0
    percentavgnum = 0
    # ...
```

2. Pass your variables as arguments of  `oneround()`:

```
percentavg = 0
percentavgnum = 0
oneround(percentavg,percentavgnum)
```

And you don't need to declare your variables as global at all.

3. Access your outer scope variables uing `global` **inside** your function:

(That's what @Blue proposed)

```
def oneround():
    global percentavg
    global percentavgnum
```

The keywork `global` is used to access the *outer scope variables* (the variables declared outside the scope of the function).

If you choose option 1, you can delete these lines at the begining of your code:

```
global percentavg
global percentavgnum
percentavg = 0
percentavgnum = 0
```

If you choose option 2, you can delete these lines at the begining of your code:

```
global percentavg
global percentavgnum
```

but you will have to keep these lines:

```
percentavg = 0
percentavgnum = 0
```

These lines could be at the beginin of your code, but it coul be in the while loop, or in the try statement, before calling `oneround()`.

But, based on your piece of code, the option 1 is the best coding practice.

Comment: So I make it global by declaring it **IN** the function?

Comment: No, you don't have to make them global at all. I will edit my answer to explain this.

Comment: I'm confused, when do I need to use this function?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a global variable and relying on a side affect of the function, write your function to accept the module level variables that need to be *updated* as arguments and to return the *updated* values.

```
>>> def f(one,two,three):
...     return one*1,two*2,three*3
...
>>> a,b,c = 'xyz'
>>> a,b,c = f(a,b,c)
>>> a
'x'
>>> b
'yy'
>>> c
'zzz'
>>>
```